# How to develop for Samsung, Panasonic and LG Smart tv app?

Tags: frontend, samsung-smart-tv, television, lg, smart-tv

I need to code the front-end development for a smart tv application that will work for **Samsung, LG and Panasonic.**

I read that Samsung has its own SDK for Eclipse and an emulator but I am not sure if developing it with Samsung SDK will work on the other two platforms, do you know if there is a way to develop it that works for all three platforms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmartTV development for starters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940572/smarttv-development-for-starters)

Answer (score 3):

There is platform difference for all the three platforms but there is framework called the TAL framework with which you can create Universal application.
Refer to BBC talframework http://fmtvp.github.io/tal/getting-started/introducing-tal.html

but i doubt that samsung QA team may not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly smart tv app are based on HTML5, Jquery, so you can build same interface for all the apps and can modify jquery according to platform(LG, Samsung, etc).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this TV SDK http://www.inio.tv/ (I am member of team who develop this...) or some other multiplatform TV framework.

If you have some questions I can answer